# Change default port for gulp serve

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am very new to spfx development. I working with two different spfx webparts and I wanted to run both of them at the same time but it run both on 4321 default port.

I try to change port in serve.json inside config folder but always run on default webpart. How can I change port

`My serve.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/core-build/serve.schema.json",
  "port": 4321,
  "https": true,
  "initialPage": "https://localhost:5432/workbench",
  "api": {
    "port": 5432,
    "entryPath": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench/lib/api/"
  }
}
```

Comment: will it be possible for you to share serve.json ?

Comment: @Ravi I have updated my question with serve.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this but can you try like this :

**First webpart's config.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/core-build/serve.schema.json",
  "port": 4321,
  "https": true,
  "initialPage": "https://localhost:5432/workbench",
  "api": {
  "port": 5432,
  "entryPath": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench/lib/api/"
  }
}
```

**Second webpart's config.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/core-build/serve.schema.json",
  "port": 4321,
  "https": true,
  "initialPage": "https://localhost:5432/workbench",
  "api": {
  "port": 8080, //Changed Port Number here
  "entryPath": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench/lib/api/"
  }
}
```

Now run gulp serve for both the webparts and both webparts should use the different port to display respective webpart.

Let me know if this works.